# Android passing arguments to activity from non-activity class

Tags: java, android

I have this problem...

I have activity(CartActivity) that starts another activity(FindItemActivity).

In FindItemActivity there is an expandlableListView(build by custom expandalbleListAdapter) with Buttons(AddItem) with custom ActionListener(OnclickListener)

I would like to pass arguments from my actionListener to first activity(CartActivity).

Here is what i have right now(in my on click listener):

```
public class addOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
Product toAdd;
Context toEnd;
public addOnClickListener(Product addable, Context context){
    this.toAdd = addable;
    this.toEnd = context;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(toEnd,MyCartActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    i.putExtra("Name", this.toAdd.name);
    i.putExtra("Code", String.valueOf(this.toAdd.code));
    i.putExtra("Price", String.valueOf(this.toAdd.price));
    toEnd.startActivity(i);

}
}
```

But, every time the button is pressed application starts NEW CartActivity, instead of the old one, that is already running... I need data stored in original activity, so I have to resume it, not to start a new one...
The compiler tells me FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is necessary when starting an activity from non-activity class.

Is there any other flag that can be used to resume activity instead of starting a new one?

Or maybe can I close somehow activity FindItemActivity? I tried finish() but I was unable to find a way to use it in non-activity class...

Comment: when you call the second activity, call it using startActivityForResult() method... that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I rightly understand, all you want is to start another activity for choosing something and return back to your first activity.

If I am right, you must call `startActivityForResult` ([read more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)) method in your first activity, and override `onActivityResult` ([read more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)) method in that first activity for receiving the result from your second activity.

Before you close the second activity, in which the user must take a choice, you must populate your result intent with data you want to pass back to the first activity. ([read more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29))

If you define your `OnCLickListener` in the same file as your `FindItemActivity`, you can close it using this code `FindItemActivity.this.finish()` from `OnClickListener`. Otherwise you can pass link of you activity class to `OnClickListener` and invoke the finish method using this link.

Comment: Hmm, that's actually nice, but how can I use this Listener (initiated in FindItemActivity) in my expandableListAdapter?

Comment: I think you can define both OnClickListener and expandableListAdapter in FindItemActivity file. Or as I say you must pass link of activity to your FindItemActivity class.

Comment: I'm getting a little bit confused... 

Let's say I would like to define them all separately. 

I'm passing Context of my FindItemActivity to expandableListAdapter, and then expandableListAdapter passes it to my ObClickListener. 
So, I have this Context there, but I don't know how to use it.

Basicly, what i have to do in there is:

Comment: 1.Prepare Intent with data to send:
 

    Intent i = new Intent();
     i.putExtra("Name", this.toAdd.name);
     i.putExtra("Code", String.valueOf(this.toAdd.code));
     i.putExtra("Price", String.valueOf(this.toAdd.price));
 
2.Send my data as a result:
 

    ((FindItemActivity)toEnd).setResult(1, i); // this isn't working...
 
3.Finish my FindItemActivity:
 

    ((FindItemActivity)toEnd).finish(); // isn't working as well...
 
Where toEnd is Context of FindItemActivity.
Or maybe u mean something else than context when u say "link of ur activity"?

Comment: Ok, I menaged to do it with defining them in one file. Thanks!